# Google Cloud / GCP Scheduled Snapshots

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, snapshot

Recently (14th Feb 2019) Google released the "scheduled snapshot" feature for Compute Engine (https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/compute/introducing-scheduled-snapshots-for-compute-engine-persistent-disk). I've read the docs (https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/scheduled-snapshots), went through the motions (i.e. created a schedule, attached it to disks) and... no snapshots get created?
I would expect to see them in "Compute Engine" --> "Snapshots", but only the manually created ones are listed there. I can see schedules in the other tab, alright, indicating they are in use by selected disks, days pass (snapshots are to be done daily) but no new snapshots appear.

Has anyone tried the feature and got snapshots in "Compute Engine" --> "Snapshots"? Any ideas why it wouldn't work? I'm trying to back up Linux VMs.

Comment: it's interesting, I will do a reproduction and come back to you tomorrow.

Comment: I did try the scheduled snapshot and it's working fine a schedule it for each 1 hour for a disk on a running instance.

Comment: Thanks Alioua, I've set it up yesterday again and this time it worked off the bat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do it right you need to create [snapshot schedule](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/scheduled-snapshots#create_snapshot_schedule), specify the region for your disk and your frequency then create.

After that, go to your instance disk on `Disks` section under  `Compute Engine`, select your disk and click on Edit.

After that you will notice **Snapshot schedule** with value no schedule, click on the arrow drop menu and select your recent **Snapshot schedule** created above and click on `Save`.

That't it.